# Como chamar um método do controller pelo Ajax usando MVC5 no visual studio?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp

Olá, sou novo em desenvolvimento, e estou desenvolvendo uma entrada de dados onde pelo cep que o usuário digitar o sistema busca na Api do correio e o endereço referente ao cep informado, porém já vi em muitos artigos na internet, mas não estou conseguindo exito na funcionalidade.

```
 $("#icon-cep").click(function () {
       var cep = $(".cep").val();
       console.log(cep);

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("BuscaCep")',
           data: { cep: cep },
           success: function (result) {
               console.log(result);

           },
           error: function (result) {

           }

       });
```

método no controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string BuscaCep(string cep)
    {
        WebServiceCorreio.AtendeClienteClient ws = new WebServiceCorreio.AtendeClienteClient("AtendeClientePort");
        var dados = ws.consultaCEP(cep);

        if (dados != null)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dados);
            return json;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Porém ele está retornando um objeto vazio, já fiz várias alterações, mas nenhuma deu certo. Alguém pode me dar uma luz do que possa estar errado??

Comment: Troque o tipo de retorno da sua action para JsonResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque o retorno para [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) no seu método do seu `controller` e use `Json()` para formatar esses dados, ***exemplo***:

***Javascript:***

```
$("#icon-cep").click(function() 
{
   var cep = $(".cep").val();
   console.log(cep);
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '@Url.Action("BuscaCep")',
       data: { cep: cep },
       success: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
       },
       error: function (result) {

       }
    });
});
```

***Controller/Action***

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult BuscaCep(string cep)
{
    WebServiceCorreio.AtendeClienteClient ws = 
              new WebServiceCorreio.AtendeClienteClient("AtendeClientePort");
    var dados = ws.consultaCEP(cep);

    if (dados != null)
    {       
        return Json(dados);
    }

    return null;
}
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [ASP.NET MVC: Retornando e consumindo dados em JSON](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3672/aspnet-mvc-retornando-e-consumindo-dados-em-json.aspx)
- [JsonResult Type in MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/)
- [Classe JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Cara resolveu, meu problema, estava realmente, perdido, muito obrigado pela ajuda.