# C# Chamar método do Controller Asp.Net MVC5 com Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Olá, tenho um método chamado `GetData()` em meu HomeController que retorna um JSON, gostaria de passar os dados para minha View, mas sempre vem vazio, estou iniciando como desenvolvedor, e já estou a alguns dias nisso, espero que tenha sido claro e que alguém possa me ajudar...

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    List<Dados> qry = new List<Dados>();

    using (AGPEntities md = new AGPEntities())
    {
        qry = (from s in md.Painel_Grafico
               select new Dados
               {
                   id_admAtribuido = s.id,
                   admAtribuido = s.admAtribuido,
                   quantidade_admAtribuido = (int)s.quantidade_admAtribuido

               }).ToList();
    }
    return Json(qry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Não entendo muito de JavaScript e Ajax, mas o que preciso é recuperar os Dados do GetData para manipular. A seguir vai uma possível descrição do que preciso, apenas jogando no console, se conseguir isso depois eu me viro.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
               data: //O que colocar aqui?
               success: function (result) {
                   console.log(result);                      
               },
               error: function (result) {
                      console.log("erro");
               }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Essa questão aqui me serviu de base para a pergunta, mas não funcionou para mim:

[Como chamar um método do controller pelo Ajax usando MVC5 no visual studio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235451/como-chamar-um-m%C3%A9todo-do-controller-pelo-ajax-usando-mvc5-no-visual-studio)

Desde já agradeço...

[EDIT] Ao colocar o código do GetData dentro do ActionResult Index() recebo o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugando, ou acessando diretamente a `GetData()` a lista `qry` recebe algum valor e o rsultado é exibido?

Comment: Então, não sei como acessar diretamente o GetData, marquei ele no debug mas não chega a ser chamado, o que fiz foi colocar esse método dentro do ActionResult Index(), assim quando a página é carregada ele mostra os dados da qry...

Comment: essa Action está na sua `HomeController`?

Comment: Sim, esta em HomeController

Answer (score 1):

Na sua `GetData()`, se estiver utilizando o **AspNetCore** ou posterior, altere o retorno para o tipo especializado `JsonResult()`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    List<Dados> qry = new List<Dados>();

    using (AGPEntities md = new AGPEntities())
    {
        qry = (from s in md.Painel_Grafico
               select new Dados
               {
                   id_admAtribuido = s.id,
                   admAtribuido = s.admAtribuido,
                   quantidade_admAtribuido = (int)s.quantidade_admAtribuido

               }).ToList();
    }
    return new JsonResult(qry);
}
```

No seu JavaScript, se você não vai enviar nenhuma informação para o servidor, não há a necessidade de declarar o atributo data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '@Url.Action("GetData","Home")',
               //data: //O que colocar aqui? (remover)
               success: function (result) {
                   console.log(result);                      
               },
               error: function (result) {
                      console.log("erro");
               }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar você pode alterar o tipo da Controller para ActionResult.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    List<Dados> qry = new List<Dados>();

    using (AGPEntities md = new AGPEntities())
    {
        qry = (from s in md.Painel_Grafico
               select new Dados
               {
                   id_admAtribuido = s.id,
                   admAtribuido = s.admAtribuido,
                   quantidade_admAtribuido = (int)s.quantidade_admAtribuido

               }).ToList();
    }
    return Json(qry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente, o erro 404 sumiu, mas em return new JsonResult(qry) está com a mensagem; Initialize a new instance of the JsonResultClass, e no console está em branco....

Comment: Qual é versão do .Net que você está usando?

Comment: Acredito que seja isso: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

Comment: Então mantenha a sua controller como estava  `return Json(qry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Coloquei console.log("Alguma Coisa") para testar e apareceu no console, então acredito que result esteja em branco console.log(result), teria que mostrar os dados do GetData não?

Comment: alguma coisa mais que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer simplesmente pegar (GET) as informações, você tem que usar o atributo `HttpGet` na sua *Action*.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        List<Dados> qry = new List<Dados>();

        using (AGPEntities md = new AGPEntities())
        {
            qry = (from s in md.Painel_Grafico
                   select new Dados
                   {
                       id_admAtribuido = s.id,
                       admAtribuido = s.admAtribuido,
                       quantidade_admAtribuido = (int)s.quantidade_admAtribuido

                   }).ToList();
        }
        return Json(qry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

E utilizar o Get em vez no Post do jquery

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Coloquei o [HttpGet] no GetData() e fiz assim:

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });

    </script>

Mas recebo essa msg:

GET http://localhost:16187/Home/GetData 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas Mudar para get não é uma boa solução, o post trás uma mínima proteção ao conteúdo.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pq usar o verbo POST se ele quer buscar e não enviar informações para o servidor? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: @user3323405 em que controller está a sua action GetData?

Comment: Está em HomeController

Comment: Pesquisando vi que pode ser algo relacionado com Router, este projeto foi um template que peguei com Bootstrap e MVC, nele tem uma classe RoutConfig, vou dar um edit e colocar o código, vai que ajuda....

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no método Get do jquery, especifiquei mais o controller no @Url.Action

Comment: Mesmo erro....:/

Comment: Outra informação, esse script está em Layout.cshtml que é o usado em Index.cshtml